# Is Proof-of-Authority (PoA) protocol a post quantum consensus?

Tags: quantum-computing

Is PoA persistent against quantum attacks? If not, How can we make it post quantum?

I mean the PoA used with blockchains that delivers comparatively fast transactions through a consensus mechanism based on identity as a stake. In a PoA based blockchain network, machines earn the right to generate new blocks by passing a strict vetting process, which is discussed in detail in the next section. As a result, trustworthy validation machines protect PoA blockchains. These system moderators are preapproved participants who check blocks and transactions.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.coindesk.com/learn/what-is-proof-of-authority/).

Comment: Can you precise about which PoA are you speaking about?

Comment: @levgeni I mean the PoA used with blockchains that delivers comparatively fast transactions through a consensus mechanism based on identity as a stake. You can read more here: https://www.coindesk.com/learn/what-is-proof-of-authority/